# Find gaps between a min and max

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, min

Two tables
Member which consists of VoucherCode (nullable int) and Scheme (bigint)
Scheme- consists of the schemeId (bigint), mincode (int), maxcode(int)

I need to find any gaps in the vouchercodes of the members, inside the min and max codes. If mincode is 1 and maxcode is 10, and the existing vouchercodes are 2, 3 and 4 then it should bring back 1. If codes 1, 2 and 4 exist then it should bring back 3. If 1, 2 and 3 exist then it should bring back 4.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  MIN(ID + 1) FROM (
    SELECT mincode AS ID from Scheme as s UNION ALL 
    SELECT  
        MIN(vouchercode + 1)
    FROM    
        member mmm where mmm.voucherCode is not null
        ) AS T1
WHERE
    ID+1 NOT IN (SELECT vouchercode as ID FROM member m where voucherCode is not null)
```

It works but not for all 3 scenarios. If 2, 3 and 4 exist then it brings back null instead of 1. 1, 3 and 4 exist then it brings back 2, correct! 1, 2 and 3 exist and it brings back null, not 4.

Comment: This would be pretty simple with a tally table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this using a tally table. I have a view in my system with the ctes but I extracted them here. You can extend the tally table to more rows if needed.

```
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )

select MIN(t.N)
from cteTally t
left join Scheme s on s.ID = t.N
where s.ID is null
```